# Apache mod-rewrite with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I now have this two rules which work ok

```
RewriteRule ^paymentok$ ?,return,payment&status=OK
RewriteRule ^paymentfail$ ?,return,payment&status=FAIL
```

What i need is also the get parameters after the paymentok or paymentfail, i.e. when this page is accessed:

```
paymentok?myvar1=dfsdf&myvar2=ewrwe
```

then the redirected URL should be:

```
?,return,payment&status=OK&myvar1=dfsdf&myvar2=ewrwe
```

Is this possible with rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to invlude the `QSA` flag in your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^paymentok$ ?,return,payment&status=OK  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^paymentfail$ ?,return,payment&status=FAIL [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag (Query String Append) appends any existing query string to the new one that you've created in your rule's target.